# Trying to build (a)kmod package for acpi_call on Fedora, cannot be installed

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules, packaging, rpmbuild

I want to package a simple kernel module, acpi_call, for Fedora. For this I have followed the [kmods2 instructions on RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/Packaging/KernelModules/Kmods2) and got the following SPEC file:

```
# Copyright © 2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>

# A lot of boilerplate taken from
# http://rpmfusion.org/Packaging/KernelModules/Kmods2

#define buildforkernels newest
#define buildforkernels current
%define buildforkernels akmod

%define kmod_name acpi_call

%global debug_package %{nil}

Name:           %{kmod_name}
Version:        1.1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Call ACPI methods by writing to /proc

License:        GPL3+
Source0:        https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call/archive/v%{version}.tar.gz#/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

BuildRequires:  %{_bindir}/kmodtool

Requires: %{name}-kmod >= %{version}
Provides: %{name}-kmod-common = %{version}

# needed for plague to make sure it builds for i586 and i686
ExclusiveArch:  i586 i686 x86_64 ppc ppc64

# get the proper build-sysbuild package from the repo, which
# tracks in all the kernel-devel packages
BuildRequires:  %{_bindir}/kmodtool

%{!?kernels:BuildRequires: buildsys-build-rpmfusion-kerneldevpkgs-%{?buildforkernels:%{buildforkernels}}%{!?buildforkernels:current}-%{_target_cpu} }

# kmodtool does its magic here
%{expand:%(kmodtool --target %{_target_cpu} --repo rpmfusion --kmodname %{name} %{?buildforkernels:--%{buildforkernels}} %{?kernels:--for-kernels "%{?kernels}"} 2>/dev/null) }

%description

A kernel simple module that enables you to call ACPI methods by writing the
method name followed by arguments to /proc/acpi/call.

This module is to be considered a proof-of-concept and has been superseeded by
projects like bbswitch. It allows you to tamper with your system and should be
used with caution.

%prep

# error out if there was something wrong with kmodtool
%{?kmodtool_check}

%autosetup -n %{kmod_name}-%{version}

# print kmodtool output for debugging purposes:
kmodtool  --target %{_target_cpu}  --repo %{repo} --kmodname %{name} %{?buildforkernels:--%{buildforkernels}} %{?kernels:--for-kernels "%{?kernels}"} 2>/dev/null

for kernel_version in %{?kernel_versions} ; do
    cp -a foo-%{version} _kmod_build_${kernel_version%%___*}
done

%build

for kernel_version in %{?kernel_versions}; do
    make %{?_smp_mflags} -C "${kernel_version##*___}" SUBDIRS=${PWD}/_kmod_build_${kernel_version%%___*} modules
done

%install

rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

for kernel_version in %{?kernel_versions}; do
    make install DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} KMODPATH=%{kmodinstdir_prefix}/${kernel_version%%___*}/%{kmodinstdir_postfix}
    # install -D -m 755 _kmod_build_${kernel_version%%___*}/foo/foo.ko  ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{kmodinstdir_prefix}/${kernel_version%%___*}/%{kmodinstdir_postfix}/foo.ko
done
%{?akmod_install}

%clean

rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%changelog

* Sat Jul 23 2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de> 1.1.0-1
- Initial packaging
```

See [this paste](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/394231/) for a version with syntax highlighting.

It does compile with `rpmbuild -ba acpi_call.spec` and I do get two files:

- `akmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm`
- `kmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm`

When I try to install them with `dnf`, I cannot because the `-common` package is missing:

```
# dnf install akmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm kmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64.rpm 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:47:46 ago on Sat Jul 23 11:03:54 2016.
Error: nothing provides acpi_call-kmod-common >= 1.1.0 needed by akmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64.
nothing provides acpi_call-kmod-common >= 1.1.0 needed by akmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages)
```

I am now stuck here. No `-common` package is created and installing those packages with `dnf` does not seem to work either.

How can I get this into a package?

Comment: did you try  `rpm -i *.rpm`  and get the same error?

Comment: I pretty much get the same error: `acpi_call-kmod-common >= 1.1.0 is needed by akmod-acpi_call-1.1.0-1.fc24.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1):

kmodtool requires a `*-kmod-common` spec. This can be very simple package with just the basics.

```
%define modname yourmod

Name:           %{modname}-kmod-common

Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}.1
Summary:        Common files for your mod
Group:          System Environment/Kernel
License:        GPL
Source0:        ${name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
BuildArch:      noarch
```

A good example is https://github.com/neatbasis/sunhme2g

Build this with `rpmbuild` and then you can package everything with `createrepo`